# How to parameterize Firestore sub collection names in Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My Firestore sub collection names are of the format 'subcollection_name_yyyymmdd'. Whenever new documents are added, they are identified through the 'yyyymmdd' part of the subcollection name. I need to take Firestore exports for these subcollections incrementally on the 'yyyymmdd' values. Below is my cloud function taking full firestore export at the moment. Is there a way I can parameterize the **'collectionIds:'** to take the subcollection names by passing the yyyymmdd part as a variable/parameter?
eg: something like collectionIds: ['subcollection_name_{$date}']?

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME'
exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
   // process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
   "PROJECT_ID",
    '(default)'
  );
return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,

      collectionIds: ['subcollection_name'],
    })
    .then(responses => {
      const response = responses[0];
      console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
      return response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```